# How to animate AJAX post?

Tags: ajax, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

sorry for this request but I'm an AJAX beginner.
I have the following script and I'm trying to animate it (something like "fade").

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $(document).on("click",".ratingemo", function(){
     var rating = $(this).attr("id").substr(0, 1);
     var id = $(this).attr("id").substr(1);
     var data = "id="+id+"&rating="+rating;

     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/ldplug/rate.php",
       data: data,
       success: function(e){
         $("#r"+id).html(e);
       }
     })
   });
});
```

How can I do that?

Many thanks!

Comment: I take it you're not trying to fade in your code, so it isn't the script you're trying to animate, but some HTML elements on your page. Meaning you will have to show the relevant section of your HTML, and describe which portion should fade in and when.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `live` is deprecated, check out [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.  But that being said, why not:

```
success: function(e){
         $("#r"+id).hide();
         $("#r"+id).html(e).fadeIn("slow");
       }
```

It would be better to just have `$("#r"+id)` hidden to start, I just hid it to illustrate the point.

Comment: Thanks, marteljin. And yes, live is deprecated sorry. Just updated my script.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your HTML, I have to assume that something like this will work for you. Hide the element, populate it, then fade it in.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".ratings").live("click", function () {
        var rating = $(this).attr("id").substr(0, 1);
        var id = $(this).attr("id").substr(1);
        var data = "id=" + id + "&rating=" + rating;

        $("#r" + id).hide();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ratings/rate.php",
            data: data,
            success: function (e) {
                $("#r" + id).html(e);
                $("#r" + id).fadeIn();
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: No need to query the element 3 times - use methond chaining (i.e. `$(...).hide().html(e).fadeIn()`)